# Check RAID rebuild status of R710?

Tags: raid, centos6, dell-perc, dell-poweredge

How can I check the rebuild status of a RAID volume without booting into the PERC utility in CentOS via the command-line?

Comment: Probably some magic incantation [using the MegaCLI command](http://hwraid.le-vert.net/wiki/LSIMegaRAIDSAS).

Comment: PERC controllers are usually LSI devices, so MegaCLI will work for your PowerEdge R710.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found I could check the status with `MegaCli` as ewwhite mentioned:

```
MegaCli64 -PDRbld -ShowProg -PhysDrv [CONTROLLER:DRIVE] -aAll
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have Dell's OpenManage software installed, you can also use `omreport storage vdisk` to provide a summary of all virtual disks (which should include rebuild progress).

Technically megaCLI isn't considered a "supported" tool by Dell (even though I think it's probably what's being used on the back-end by OMSA), but it's still a VERY useful tool when dealing w/ PERC controllers.